# Not Able to Get Values of XML Elements Using .text()

Tags: jquery, html, xml

So at this point, I'm just trying to retrieve data from an XML file using JQuery. I'm able to load the file, but this simply returns an empty string:

JQuery:

```
    $.get('data.xml','xml',function(data){
        var names = $.parseXML(data),
            $names = $(names);
        alert($names.find('test').text());
    });
```

XML:

```
<names>
    <test>test</test>
</names>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

I'd like to be able to retrieve "test" from inside the 'test' element.

Comment: console.log(data) and check whether it is correct or not. As code seems fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, if you want to specify the dataType you have to do if after the callback.

> jQuery.get( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )

Secondly, you do not have to `.parseXML()`

```
$.get('data.xml', function(data){
    var $names = $(data);
    alert($names.find('test').text());
}, 'xml');
```

Comment: Changing that comma after $(data) to a semicolon, that worked perfectly! Thank you so much.

Comment: @TJBarber: Glad it helped. If it solved the question please mark it as answered so that other users can also find it useful